# Tensorflow error: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[768,64] labels_size=[48,64]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a simple(without the upsampling) fully-convolutional neural network. However, I have encountered the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[768,64] labels_size=[48,64]
 [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_2 = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_9, Reshape_10)]]
```

It's clear that the reason for this error is that the logits and labels have different sizes, but I have literally no idea which part of the code might be responsible for this. The dataset which is given to feed_dict seems to be ok.

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/den250400/1641d20dc31fbcf1070211451eac7628

Comment: What is the task? Classification? Object detection? What are the labels?

Comment: @Maxim The task is image segmentation(in my case, simply object detection) - so each label is 48x64 ground-truth image.

Comment: Why do you use SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits?

Comment: @Maxim I use it as my loss function. I have read somewhere on the Internet that this function also works with 2-dimensional arrays. Should I use another function in this case?

Comment: The problem is solved. The reason for this mistake was one extra convolutional layer, which reduced the size of the output image twice more than needed. The other mistake was that I forgot to merge all 64 threads into one in the last convolutional layer.